# How to connect to Mongo DB using protractor and jasmine

Tags: mongodb, protractor

I want to connect and run some queries to MongoDB but I can't find any documentation on how to do it using protractor and Jasmine.
Can anyone pls direct me to a good documentation page/article

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript having Mongodb driver.

```
npm install mongodb --save-dev
```

Install it via npm in your project.

**Connecting to MongoDB**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:2701/mydb";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("connected !");
  db.close();
});
```

**Retrieve Data from a collection**

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:2701/E2E';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    var result = db.collection('Emp').find();

    result.each(function(err, doc) {

        console.log(doc);

    });
});
```

Here we are defining a variable name called result which will be used to store the pointer to the records fetched from the database for Emp collection.later we iterate through our result.

Documentation is well maintained at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb